# trend between values in a single variable

Tags: trend

What measure can one see to find trend between values in a single variable- for e.g if a gene is always overexpressed in different conditions. Other than skewness and kurtosis are there any other measures?
I understand that the Mann-Kendall test is with respect to time
sorry if this question is very basic

Comment: `in different conditions`, i.e. when compared/conditional to/on another variable?

Comment: no, not another variable. the same variable under different conditions. for e.g fold change in different conditions w.r.t control
                      value

Comment: say in  a list of 100 values 40 values are positive, 40 neutral and 20 negative. something like ratio of number of positive/number of negative values. i mean i don't know if the values are normally distributed. any established statistical test?

Comment: You will need to define what these "different conditions" are, otherwise it could it be anything.

Comment: each condition is a experimental condition. i set up 100 such different conditions to perturb a biological sample along with untreated controls. compared to the untreated control, one gene registers no change in levels, another gene rises in levels in 40 different conditions  and yet another gene rises in 5 such conditions while reduces in 50 conditions. can I comment on this variability (not correlation with each other) but the change in levels?